# Changing Facebook login permissions with iOS Swift SDK 0.2.0

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I am just using login for Udacity project and don't need access to user info.

Here I add the button and set read permissions to be an empty array.

```
let facebookButton = LoginButton.init(frame: loginButton.frame, readPermissions: [])
facebookLoginButton.delegate = self
view.addSubview(facebookButton)
```

My question is why does the auto-generated dialog alert controller tell the user that my app and the website will be sharing info about them?

And then results returned from the LoginButtonDelegate method:

```
func loginButtonDidCompleteLogin(_ loginButton: LoginButton, result: LoginResult) {
   print(result)
}
```

shows permissions granted for public profile and email:

> Set([FacebookCore.Permission(name: "public_profile"), FacebookCore.Permission(name: "email")]), declinedPermissions: Set([]), etc

Is there somewhere else that I need to set the read permissions other than the Login Button initializer?

Facebook best practices in documents said to only request permissions that are needed. That is why I am trying to change this.

Comment: public_profile is the most basic login permission, and allows access to the following fields: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions#reference-public_profile You can not let users login without _any_ permissions; public_profile is an implicit default.

Comment: Got it. Thank you. It seems the email permission comes automatically too. Adding it or removing it does effect result, whereas the "users friends" read permission works as expected.

Comment: No, you need `email` permission to access a user's email address. You likely already granted it to the app before. (Removing it from the list of permissions you ask for doesn't also un-grant the permission.)

Comment: Ok. Udacity asked that I use their app ID for the project. Maybe they enabled it on the facebook dashboard or somewhere else before I set the read permissions.